# Sklearn fbeta_score default average parameter not working with multiclass target variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I want to use f2-score to evaluate my model,but there is an error.

```
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
ftwo_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2) # beta=2
```

U can see , I use `fbeta_score` and `make_scorer` to define a metrics of mine. But when I apply this metrics to `fit`, there is an error.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
svc = SVC()
parameters = { 'C':[100,1000]}
             #'gamma':[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3]}}
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, scoring=ftwo_scorer,cv=5)
clf.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain,)
Yval_pred = clf.predict(Xval)
```

Error messege:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-600-ebf059724dd4> in <module>
      4               #'gamma':[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3]}
      5 clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, scoring=ftwo_scorer,cv=5)
----> 6 clf.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
      7 Yval_pred = clf.predict(Xval)
……
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose
another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening cause your target variable `Y` has probably more than two classes. By default `fbeta_score` set average to binary targets.

So, as the error suggest pass a different `average` value of these options `[None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted']` to the `make_scorer` function, i.e.

```
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer


ftwo_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2, average='weighted')
```